# basic haskell : Converting Type to Int

Tags: haskell

If I have a type, eg insurance number which is a int.

Is there anyway I can convert insurancenumber to int for use in a comparing function?

```
intNI :: NI -> Int
intNI x = Int (x)
```

Comment: It all depends on how `NI` is defined. Try `intNI x = fromIntegral x`, or maybe `intNI (NI x) = x`.

Comment: If you are planning to compare two `NI` then derive them as instance of typeclass `Ord`

Comment: intNI (NI x) = x worked thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as I suspect, `NI` is defined as

```
type NI = Int
```

then you can just say

```
intNI :: NI -> Int
intNI x = fromIntegral x
```

or, after eta-conversion:

```
intNI :: NI -> Int
intNI = fromIntegral
```

---

On the other hand, it seems that

```
data NI = NI Int
```

in which case the right way to go is pattern matching, like so:

```
intNI (NI x) = x
```

This will extract the `x` bit out of `NI x` and return it.

Comment: If `type NI = Int`, then `intNI = id`.